# WindowsPackageType is set to None, but GenerateAppxPackageOnBuild is set to true

Tags: maui, maui-blazor, maui-windows, maui-community-toolkit

I created the .exe for the .net Maui Project by changing Some of the Code Like `<WindowsPackageType>None</WindowsPackageType>`
and in launch Setting File Changed the Command name to Project.

Now, I want to create the MSIX for the Same project I changed the Command name to MsixProject and Removed `<WindowsPackageType>None</WindowsPackageType>`
But it is giving the error

> WindowsPackageType is set to None, but GenerateAppxPackageOnBuild is set to true.

I create a new project and Follow the same Steps to create MSIX I am able to Create the MSIX.

What is the default value for WindowsPackageType so I will be able to create the MSIX for the project.

Comment: Did you try to set the WindowsPackageType as MSIX?

Answer (score 1):

Try this `<WindowsPackageType>MSIX</WindowsPackageType>`. When use msbuild for create msix then dont use /p:GenerateAppxPackageOnBuild=true in command.
My command is e.g.

```html
msbuild /restore /t:Publish /p:TargetFramework=net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0 /p:configuration=release /p:AppxPackageSigningEnabled=true /p:PackageCertificateThumbprint={crtThumb} /p:PackageCertificatePassword={crtPass}
```

Answer (score 0):

VS 2022 17.4 Don't work.

I worked witd dotnet.

```
dotnet publish -f net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0 -c Release /p:RuntimeIdentifierOverride=win10-x64 /p:PublishReadyToRunShowWarnings=true
```